# .exe in folder "not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I am aware that this is a frequently asked question on SU, but I cannot find the solution to my problem in other answers.

I have a .exe that is in a folder on my desktop. I have changed directory into this folder, but when I try to run the .exe, whether by typing its name, typing the full path to the .exe, or typing the full path in quotes, I keep getting the "not recognized as an internal or external command".

Is this a Windows 10 64-bit error? Is there any way I can resolve it - I don't think adding the path to the environment variable will help here...

Comment: Just putting an ".exe" at the end of some file's name does not make it executable. You need to analyze the file with some software capable of reading Windows executable file formats.

Comment: The file is an executable. I've run it effectively on other systems

Comment: a few things to check: `echo %pathext%`: is `.exe` listed? `assoc .exe`: is it `exefile`? `ftype exefile`: is it `"%1" %*`?

Comment: It sounds like what you are seeing might not really be there. Open a command prompt and navigate to it. Then see if it is there and will run.

Comment: Examine the file in a hex editor. Look at the beginning. Does it begin **MZ[nul]**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved - the issue was (as Refurb's comment above suggested) that the apparent path was not the true path - there was a folder in the path that the system could not read the name of (but which didn't appear when navigating in cmd.exe). Moving the whole folder above this unreadable folder fixed the problem.

Thanks to comments above!